Auto redirect me to /build "domain.com/build" in laravel 11 and vue.js 3
after run npm run build and open localhost:8000 auto redirect me to localhost:8000/build
vite.config.js :
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    base: '/',
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                manualChunks: {
                    vendor: ['vue', 'axios', 'smoothscroll-polyfill', 'vue3-star-ratings', 'vue-sweetalert2'], // add other common libraries you want to separate
                },
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/js/main.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js'),
        },
    },
});

/public/.htaccess :
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

i add   base: '/' to vite.config.js and run
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear


and run after
npm run build

website work normally localhost:8000/build for the first time , but when i reload the page gets error :
Not Found
The requested resource /build/ was not found on this server.
